# python,sockets,не на локальной сети

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import socket
import threading
server = socket.socket(
    socket .AF_INET,
    socket.SOCK_STREAM,
)
server.bind(
    ("{МОЙ ВНЕШНИЙ IP}", 25565)

)
server.listen()
users = []


def send_all(data):
    for user in users:
        user.send(data.encode())



def listen_user(user):
    while True:
        data = user.recv(1024).decode()
        print(data)
        send_all(data)



def start_server():

 while True:

     user_socket, address = server.accept()
     users.append(user_socket)
     print(address[0])
     listen_accepted_user = threading.Thread(target=listen_user, args=(user_socket,))
     listen_accepted_user.start()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server()
```

при запуске получаю:
server.bind(
OSError: [WinError 10049] Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен

Comment: Видимо, вы пытаетесь использовать адрес, который вам на самом деле не принадлежит

Comment: ip мой  с сайта 2ip

Comment: Это не обязательно значит, что показанный там ip принадлежит именно вам

Comment: а как тогда его узнать?

Comment: Посмотреть в свойствах сетевого адаптера в настройках системы. Вы можете использовать только те IP-адреса, которые указаны там (или можно добавить какой-нибудь новый статический IP-адрес, но с ним не будет связи и поэтому в этом нет смысла)

Comment: на сколько я знаю там только внутренний ip адрес, а мне нужно что-бы работало на внешнем

Comment: Тогда выясняйте, кто реально владеет внешним ip-адресом, и просите его перенаправить входящие запросы на ваш внутренний ip-адрес. Если вам везёт, то ваш интернет-провайдер уже предоставляет вам внешний ip-адрес и он находится на вашем роутере — тогда вам просто нужно прописать перенаправление портов в настройках вашего роутера. Если вам не везёт, то интернет-провайдер спрятал вас за NAT и вам нужно покупать дополнительную услугу у него (если он её вообще предоставляет), ну или просто менять провайдера

Comment: спасибо.........

Comment: server.bind в качестве первого аргумента принимает IP-адрес какого-либо из сетевых интерфейсов.
Соответственно там, где у вас {МОЙ ВНЕШНИЙ IP}, должен стоять IP-адрес одного из сетевых интерфейсов вашего ПК. Посмотреть IP-адреса можно в сведениях о сетевых адаптерах вашей ОС. Учитывая, что вам нужен доступ из интернета, вам следует указать IP-адрес того сетевого интерфейса, который смотрит в интернет.
Уже после этого следует разбираться с тем, куплена ли у вас услуга внешнего IP, перенаправлены ли порты и т. д.

Comment: есть ли какая-то программа ?